# Как, с помощью команды fputc записать двухзначное число в файл. СИ

Tags: c

У меня есть файл с текстом, и в этом файле нужно найти количество определенных слов, и потом это количество слов записать в этот же файл. Пропустим часть кода, где эти слова считаются и вот получается такой код:

Использовать нужно только fputc!

```
   f = 20; // Количество слов в тексте  
   vysl = (char)f + '0';
   FILE*  tspp = fopen(argv[1], "w");
   fputc(vysl, tspp);
   fclose(tspp);
    
   // На выходе в файле я получаю знак "D"
   // Хочу получить 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Двузначное?

```
fputc(f/10+'0',tspp);
fputc(f%10+'0',tspp);
```